# Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes

Tags: javascript, react-native

Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like this doesn't contain a question. Please see [ask]. Also, add enough detail so others can help. Did you try doing what the error message suggests?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.